# Cant read property disabled in javascript

Tags: javascript

Hey guys am new to javscript..I have heard of javascript `.disabled` property and i have decided to do with it ..So the code i have writen is

```
<html>
  <body>
    <input name="I_can_fly">
    var c = document.getElementById('I_can_fly');
    var m = c.disabled ? true : false;
    console.log(c);
  </body>
</html>
```

When i run the above code i got an error like  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'disabled' of null`. I dont know what am doing wrong..

Any help would be really appreciated ..Thanks in advance

Comment: let me know why the downvote is for

Comment: Worth pointing out - your `input` tag should be inside the `body`, not outside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing `getElementById`.  Add an ID to your input.

**edit** added the script tags, as mentioned by Amit.

```
<html>
<body>
<input name="bae" id="bae">
<script>
  var c = document.getElementById('bae');
  var m = c.disabled ? true : false;
  console.log(c);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Though I absolutely abhor your use of the term 'bae'.

Answer (score 0):

Your input is missing an id:

```
<input id="bae" name="bae">
```

Comment: sorry. I'm not sure how I ended up editing your answer instead of mine.

Comment: Haha it's no problem I think we all gave the same answer any way.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the javascript inside the `<script>` tag. And since `disabled` returns the Boolean, you can just assign it to `m` and add `id` attribute to the input `<input id="bae" />`

```
<script>
  var c = document.getElementById('bae');
  var m = c.disabled;
</script>
```